# How to represent the following border matrix in latex?

Tags: amsmath, bordermatrix

[image]

I have tried and st-rucked in between. My main query is how to place the curly brace so that it covers entire T11 to T1p1, as shown in the attached image. Does there exist any syntax similar to `\Biggl` in terms of more coverage. The MWE is as follows. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
ETC_{ij}= 
\begin{blockarray}{c@{\,}ccccc}
\vspace{0.2cm}
&& C_{1} & C_{2} & \cdots & C_{m} \\
\begin{block}{c@{\,}c[cccc]}
&T_{11} & ETC_{11,1} & ETC_{11,2} & \cdots & ETC_{11,m} \\
&T_{12} & ETC_{12,1} & ETC_{12,2} & \cdots & ETC_{12,m} \\
\smash{\raisebox{5pt}{$\Biggl\{$}}&
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&T_{1p1} & ETC_{1p1,1} & ETC_{1p1,2} & \cdots & ETC_{1p1,m} \\
&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&T_{n1} & ETC_{n1,1} & ETC_{n1,2} & \cdots & ETC_{n1,m} \\
&T_{n2} & ETC_{n2,1} & ETC_{n2,2} & \cdots & ETC_{n2,m} \\
\smash{\raisebox{2pt}{$\Biggl\{$}}&
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&T_{npn} & ETC_{npn,1} & ETC_{npn,2} & \cdots & ETC_{npn,m} \\  \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't have many of these in your document! `;-)`

The idea is good, you just have to use extensible delimiters. I also added a couple of tricks to induce `blkarray` to use slightly bigger fences than it normally would, rather than blank lines or explicit spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
ETC_{ij}= 
\begin{blockarray}{c@{\,}ccccc}
&& C_{1} & C_{2} & \cdots & C_{m} \\
\begin{block}{c@{\,}c[cccc]}
&T_{11} & ETC_{11,1} & ETC_{11,2} & \cdots & ETC_{11,m}\smash[b]{\vphantom{\bigg|}} \\
&T_{12} & ETC_{12,1} & ETC_{12,2} & \cdots & ETC_{12,m} \\
\smash{%
  \raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{%
    $A_1\left\{
    \vphantom{\begin{array}{c} \\ \\ \\ \\ \end{array}}
    \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$%
  }%
}
&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&T_{1p1} & ETC_{1p1,1} & ETC_{1p1,2} & \cdots & ETC_{1p1,m} \\
&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&T_{n1} & ETC_{n1,1} & ETC_{n1,2} & \cdots & ETC_{n1,m} \\
&T_{n2} & ETC_{n2,1} & ETC_{n2,2} & \cdots & ETC_{n2,m} \\
\smash{%
  \raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{%
    $A_n\left\{
    \vphantom{\begin{array}{c} \\ \\ \\ \\ \end{array}}
    \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$%
  }%
}
&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
&T_{npn} & ETC_{npn,1} & ETC_{npn,2} & \cdots & ETC_{npn,m}\smash[t]{\vphantom{\bigg|}} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You @egreg. Is there exist any way to represent the above mentioned matrix without using the delimiters?

Comment: @SibaMishra What delimiters are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
ETC_{ij}= 
\begin{NiceMatrix}
    && C_{1} & C_{2} & \cdots & C_{m} \\
    \Block{4-1}{A_1}
    &T_{11} & ETC_{11,1} & ETC_{11,2} & \cdots & ETC_{11,m} \\
    &T_{12} & ETC_{12,1} & ETC_{12,2} & \cdots & ETC_{12,m} \\
    &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    &T_{1p1} & ETC_{1p1,1} & ETC_{1p1,2} & \cdots & ETC_{1p1,m} \\
    &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \Block{4-1}{A_1}
    &T_{n1} & ETC_{n1,1} & ETC_{n1,2} & \cdots & ETC_{n1,m} \\
    &T_{n2} & ETC_{n2,1} & ETC_{n2,2} & \cdots & ETC_{n2,m} \\
    &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    &T_{npn} & ETC_{npn,1} & ETC_{npn,2} & \cdots & ETC_{npn,m} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{2-3}{10-6}]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{2-2}{5-2}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{7-2}{10-2}{.}
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]